# Connecting to databases via ODBC with python on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc

I have a flask app written in python. I would like to include a form where users can specify everything needed to setup an ODBC and then remotely send queries via the ODBC.

I'm trying to use [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/) (since I'm on OSX) and [pyodbc](http://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/) (since my app is python-based).

I've followed the `pyodbc` docs for setting up an ODBC:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdb;UID=me;PWD=pass')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

I've gotten this to work by installing `psqlodbc` via homebrew and then specifying `/usr/local/Cellar/psqlodbc/09.03.0300/lib/psqlodbcw.so` as the driver.

But I have 3 questions:

1. Is there an easy way to get all the other ODBC drivers (eg. via homebrew)?
2. How can I specify the driver as `PostgreSQL` instead of by the file path? Is this what `FreeTDS` is for?
3. What is `{SQL Server}`? Is this some general purpose driver compatible with any SQL-compatible database?

Answer (score 1):

1. A cursory Google would suggest the answer is no. There are a *lot* of possible drivers, so it would be useful to install the most widely used (SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle, MySQL etc) and let your users know which drivers are available to them
2. `cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={PostgreSQL};Server=IP address;Port=5432;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;')` should work as taken from [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql-odbc-driver-psqlodbc/)
3. [{SQL Server}](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/) refers to [Microsoft SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)

Comment: If you're going to be connecting to Microsoft SQL Server from *nix (my apologies if you are), you'll want to use the FreeTDS driver (http://www.freetds.org/software.html), which translates between unixODBC and MS SQL Server TDS format.